# Angularjs: ng-repeat filter object within array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I have created a plunker which explains what I am trying to achieve.
http://plnkr.co/edit/XAghimH20qwxQGjO42gP?p=preview

I have this array of objects $scope.menus

```
    $scope.menus = [
          {   
            name: 'Access',
            submenu: [
              { name: 'User List'},
            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'Organization',
            submenu: [
              { name: 'City List'}, 
              { name: 'State List'},
              { name: 'Country List'},
            ]
          },
{
            name: 'Upload Logs',
            submenu: [
                { name: 'Inventory Uploads'},
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Bulk Logs',
            submenu: [
                { name: 'Bulk Renewals'},
            ]
        },
        ];
```

For the outside menu when searched, for eg like `Access` or `Organization`, only the searched item is returned.

But when inside menu is searched, for eg like `City List`, in result I get all the other objects also including `City List`.
I was expecting to get only `City List`.

I have observed that for a nested array of objects, the filter is not working.

I may be wrong. Please guide me learning something new.

**UPDATE**
@Vivek solution worked. But now I am facing another issue. I have added some other arrays to my existing array.
 As I type `Bulk` or `upload` in the search field, the submenu appears. But as soon as I typing the second word (for eg `Bulk logs` or `upload logs`), the submenu disappears. 
If it had appeared when first word was typed, why did it disappeared when the second word was type.Why is it happening?

**UPDATE**
Thank you all for your time and responses.

Comment: There are two exclusive filters in your code, they are not related and hence are pure pattern matches in their own array. I'd suggest you to remove the filter from the top ng-repeat.

Comment: Checked it. If I do so, all the main menus are displayed, with the searched submenu if any. Is there a way to hide the upper menu if not submenu is found?

Comment: Updated the answer, that might work for your use case, take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter is only applied to the first loop, you need to add the filter on the submenu `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS ng-repeat filter</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="democontroller">

      <input type="text" placeholder="Search text" ng-model="menuSearch">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menu in menus | filter : menuSearch">
            <span href="#">{{menu.name}}</span>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.submenu | filter: menuSearch"> <!--Notice filter added here-->
                    <a href="#">{{submenu.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

For your updated usecase, this might help, basically there is filter on the submenu, but the main menu is showed if the submenu is active or the search contains any of the text from menu:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS ng-repeat filter</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="democontroller">

      <input type="text" placeholder="Search text" ng-model="menuSearch">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menu in menus"  ng-if="(menu.submenu | filter: menuSearch).length > 0  || (menu.name.includes(menuSearch))">
            <span href="#">{{menu.name}}</span>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.submenu | filter : menuSearch">
                    <a href="#">{{submenu.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That fixed it, but now I am facing other issue. Posting it now. I have updated the PLUNKER.

Comment: I have updated the plunker with new issue and array. Please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: I will revert after I have checked. Thank you for response. Good night

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>   <input type="text" placeholder="Search text" ng-model="menuSearch">
>   <ul>
>     <li ng-repeat="menu in menus | filter : menuSearch">
>         <span href="#">{{menu.name}}</span>
>         <ul>
>             <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.submenu | filter : menuSearch">
>                 <a href="#">{{submenu.name}}</a>
>             </li>
>         </ul>
>     </li>
>   </ul>
>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

you have to also write filter in sub menu ng-repeat like below,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS ng-repeat filter</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="democontroller">

      <input type="text" placeholder="Search text" ng-model="menuSearch">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menu in menus | filter : menuSearch">
            <span href="#">{{menu.name}}</span>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.submenu | filter : menuSearch">
                    <a href="#">{{submenu.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works, but some new issues have come. I have updated the plunker. Please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: because of Log word is not present in your submenu

Comment: you should  have to make to search boxes one for menu and second for submenu it will solve your issue

Comment: Can't do that sir, I need the single box to search both the menus. Can there be some custom filter made to resolve such issue where if nothing found in submenu, whole submenu is displayed, would this be possible?

Comment: for that you have to write your own custom filter

Comment: Can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: what is your requirement for this search filter? means what you enter in search box which filter both menu submenu ?

Comment: I just have this sidebar menu in my project. This filter is for searching menus. That is why I need to know where am I going wrong

Comment: then put search filter only in submenu. menu displayed but submenu only matched with search text

Comment: But if I do so, then if no match is found in any other main menu, those menus are just displayed with the one in which the match was found.

Comment: menu Item did not show any page only submenu did right?

Comment: yes, submenu is for interaction as you said, but if I follow your approach, then I must atleast hide the menus with no submenu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181438/discussion-between-steve-and-hitesh-kansagara).